# How do I get latitude and longtitude for desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net

Can I get latitude and longtitude on windows 7 desktop application?

Usually it will work on mobile or tablet using GPS, 3G or WiFi.

But how I get the coordinate using c#?

Comment: what is the goal exactly ? does the machine have a GPS sensor and/or do you want to get a country based on a public IP address ? what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Offcourse you  can, you even can get the altitude and speed!

Comment: @HaLaBi it is even possible to get temporal coordinates :-)

Comment: @Yahia sure it is pissible. In windows 8 you will be able to get the user's temeprature

Comment: @HaLaBi I think it comes with a virtual tricorder built-in...

Comment: If you wish to get those co-ordinates from a geographical place (spcifying it) than just from a device, then use some web service related to that. I did once use ip2location.com web service to get the details of a ip address. It had those coordinates too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard GPS device (internal or external) sends data on a serial port. Receiving any data from [Serial Port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) is very easy. Please [check this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c#/).

```
    //define serial port
    SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();

    //configuring the serial port
    serialPort1.PortName="COM1";
    serialPort1.BaudRate=9600;
    serialPort1.DataBits=8;
    serialPort1.Parity=Parity.None;
    serialPort1.StopBits= StopBits.One;

   //read data from serial port
   string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
```

GPS data is composed on [NMEA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) protocol. The data itself is just ascii text and may extend over multiple sentences e.g.

- GGA
- GSA
- GSV
- RMC

Sample data from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA) below.

```
$GPGGA,092750.000,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,1,8,1.03,61.7,M,55.2,M,,*76
$GPGSA,A,3,10,07,05,02,29,04,08,13,,,,,1.72,1.03,1.38*0A
$GPGSV,3,1,11,10,63,137,17,07,61,098,15,05,59,290,20,08,54,157,30*70
$GPGSV,3,2,11,02,39,223,19,13,28,070,17,26,23,252,,04,14,186,14*79
$GPGSV,3,3,11,29,09,301,24,16,09,020,,36,,,*76
$GPRMC,092750.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,0.02,31.66,280511,,,A*43
```

The appropriate string you can use for location data (Latitude/Longitude) is RMC.

```
$GPRMC,092750.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,0.02,31.66,280511,,,A*43
```

It's information is described [here](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/#gga)

```
$GPRMC,225446,A,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,000.5,054.7,191194,020.3,E*68


       225446       Time of fix 22:54:46 UTC
       A            Navigation receiver warning A = OK, V = warning
       4916.45,N    Latitude 49 deg. 16.45 min North
       12311.12,W   Longitude 123 deg. 11.12 min West
       000.5        Speed over ground, Knots
       054.7        Course Made Good, True
       191194       Date of fix  19 November 1994
       020.3,E      Magnetic variation 20.3 deg East
       *68          mandatory checksum
```

For complete GPS data parsing you can [check this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9115/Writing-Your-Own-GPS-Applications-Part-2). Hopefully it will help.