# How to get GPS location in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i have to develop application which take GPS location , Can anybody tell how to get correct location To C# desktop application ?

Comment: please check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442529/how-do-i-get-latitude-and-longtitude-for-desktop-application

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the GPS receiver through the [COM port](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/communicating-with-serial-port-in-C-Sharp/) (receivers usually connect to devices via Bluetooth virtual COM ports). Then, receiving current location is a simple matter of parsing [NMEA sentences](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) (usually $GPGGA or $GPGLL).

Comment: No, but you can write it very quickly - even using plain standard C# assemblies. Have you tried?

Comment: @user2408317 - You need special hardware to get GPS data. Normal desktop PCs don't come with a GPS receiver. You *could* probably use some of the new features of HTML5, but even then the position would not be precise at all.